# JSON is object instead of array, if array_diff returns assoc array on Collection->toArray()

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, filtering, reindex

My issue is in my json I am expecting an array, but am getting an object.

Details:

I have an array of numbers:

```
$numbers = [1];
```

I select from relationship, the "drawn numbers":

```
    $drawnNumbers = Ball::whereIn('number', $numbers)->where('game_id', $card->game->id)->get()->map(function($ball) {
        return $ball->number;
    })->toArray();
```

I do a `->toArray()` here. I want to find the numbers in `$numbers` that do not occur in `$drawnNumbers`. I do so like this:

```
$numbersNotYetDrawn = array_diff($numbers, $drawnNumbers);
```

My method then `return $numbersNotYetDrawn` (my headers accept is application/json).

So now the issue. When `$drawnNumbers` is an empty array, then the printed json is a regular array like this:

```
[
    1
]
```

However if the relationship returns `$drawnNumbers` to be an array with numbers, then json is printed as an object:

```
{
    "0" => 1
}
```

Does anyone know why this is? Anyway to ensure that json is array?

Edit:

Here is my actual data:

```
$drawnNumbers = Ball::whereIn('number', $numbers)->where('game_id', $card->game->id)->get()->map(function($ball) {
            return $ball->number;
        })->toArray();

$undrawnNumbers = array_diff($numbers, $drawnNumbers);
// $undrawnNumbers = array_values(array_diff($numbers, $drawnNumbers)); // temp fix
```

Answer (score 4):

Replace

```
$numbersNotYetDrawn = array_diff($numbers, $drawnNumbers);
```

with

```
$numbersNotYetDrawn = array_values(array_diff($numbers, $drawnNumbers));
```

to make sure element keys are reset and array is treated as a simple list and serialized to a JSON list - instead of being treated as an associative array and serialized to a JSON object.

Comment: Thank you this fixes it, and was the workaround I was using. But I was trying to understand it. How come its becoming an assoc array? Is it the implemntation of `array_diff` I dont see this in the docs.

Comment: Could you paste the actual arguments you’re passing? It could be data-dependent

Comment: Excuse my major delay please @jedrzej my data is here - https://gist.github.com/blagoh/66033fa907b5cab5f848bff376667913 - I will add it to original post now.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this same problem and wondered the same thing.
I solved it by adding "array_values", but I was wondering how to reproduce it.
I found it that it is reproduced when `array_diff` removes an element from the array that isn't the last element. So:

```
>>> $x
=> [
     1,
     2,
     3,
     4,
     5,
   ]
>>> array_diff($x, [5]);
=> [
     1,
     2,
     3,
     4,
   ]
>>> array_diff($x, [1]);
=> [
     1 => 2,
     2 => 3,
     3 => 4,
     4 => 5,
   ]
```